# How to see the firebase server log for my android firebase mlkit calls?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-mlkit, google-mlkit

I have all the code working for this project: "Detect objects in images with ML Kit for Firebase: Android" with the Nexus 6P API 29 emulator. (See my other self-answered questions on that here on stackoverflow.) Note that it is working best with the Nexus 6P API 29 so far.

I now want to see if my local run is accessing the firebase server and using its more powerful algorithm or if it is using the local algorithm, so naturally I want to see the server log.  I've looked around on my firebase console (console.firebase.google.com) but I don't see it yet.

Would be nice if I could see the log in realtime, i.e. while step-debugging through my local code in Android Studio.

How do I view the server log in general?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to see requests sent to the Cloud AI Vision API in the Cloud console: https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer

Comment: Thanks. I upvoted your answer, but I don't yet have enough reputation for it to show publicly.

Comment: Is there a link from firebase to this?  Otherwise, how would people even know that this link even exists?

Comment: On the ML Kit tab of the Firebase console, there is a link (top right) to view Cloud API usage, which takes you to graphs showing usage. Fair point about the logs though. We'll get that added to the documentation.